# Eigen Spline module Assertion

Tags: eigen, spline, assertion

I'm using spline module in Eigen, and Assertion failed when I set the type of `Spline<double, 1>` as member variables.
this is a example,

```
#include "Eigen/eigen"
#include "unsupported/Eigen/splines"
using namespace Eigen;
class Spline1d
{
   Spline<double, 1> spl1d;
public:
   ~Spline1d() {};
   Spline1d() {};
   Spline1d(const MatrixXd &input) {
      spl1d = SplineFitting<Spline<double, 1> >::Interpolate(input.row(1), 1, input.row(0));
   }
};
int main()
{
   MatrixXd vals(2, 5);
   vals << 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0,
          1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0;

   // Spline1d spl(vals);                  // case 1
   Spline<double, 1> spl1d =       // case 2
         SplineFitting<Spline<double, 1>>::Interpolate(vals.row(1), 1, vals.row(0));
   return 0;
}
```

comment `case 1` , using `case 2`, it works fine.

But comment `case 2`, using `case 1`, it fails, and it is run time error.
this is the Error message in command line，

```
Assertion failed: v == T(Value), file d:\onedrive\documents\codes\library\eigen\
src/Core/util/XprHelper.h, line 53
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case 2 is not an assignment, but a constructor.

Change your case 1 to

```
Spline1d(const MatrixXd &input)
 : spl1d(SplineFitting<Spline<double, 1> >::Interpolate(input.row(1), 1, input.row(0))){
}
```

and it will build.

Comment: that works, so Spline<> type need initializing at declaration.  Thank you very much.